# Flutter : How can i Compare two items in a list in the same index

Tags: flutter

Well, I have an app that I can enter the list of words and their translations, I have another section that I can create a quiz from the same lists that I entered, for example, I first see the word as a flash card and the section On the back of the flash card, I have to enter the translation of the word myself (TextFormField) and then I have to check to see if the word matches its translation or not,And well, I got into trouble in the last part, I can not check the translation.

```
final List <Vocabulary> vocabularyList ;

int _index = 0 ;

String currentQuestion = "";
String currentAnswer = "";


@override
void initState() {
currentQuestion = widget.vocabularyList[_index].word ;
currentQuestion = widget.vocabularyList[_index].translation ;
super.initState();
}
*********************
TextFormField(
validator: (value){
if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
 return 'Please enter Your answer';
}
return null;
},
decoration: const InputDecoration(
hintText: "your answer",),),
ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
_checkAns();}
},
child: const Text("analysis"))
*******************
void _checkAns(){
if(currentQuestion == widget.vocabularyList[_index].translation){
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
 const SnackBar(content: Text('Correct')),
);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all here you are setting the same instance of the String two times:

currentQuestion = widget.vocabularyList[_index].word ;
currentQuestion = widget.vocabularyList[_index].translation ;

and each time the value will be equals to the second line because that is the last to compile, so the value of currentQuestion will always be equal to widget.vocabularyList[_index].translation, second if you want to check that the inputed string matches the translated one by the index you can do :

_textInputController.text == currentQuestion;
this will be true or false( alternately you can use contains to see if the inputed text contains some of the string stored in the currentQuestion variable).

Comment: Thank you so much , now i have another problem , because it is correct when i write the first translation in my list, should i make a list again ? or should i make a _index property ? @wesleyhodaj

Comment: You could try it with a list, but speaking of it this is  how you learn programming, by doing it, try it yourself and see what fits you best.